# Like statement to match part of string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I am using a script to update product prices in Magento from a CSV.

Currently the SKU's in the CSV dont match exactly to the SKU's in Magento. For example one in the CSV maybe `33456` but in Magento it will be `003456_01` or `003456_02`. So I need the script to only match the middle portion of the SKU so if there are `00` or `_01` after the SKU in Magento it will still update them all that match that SKU before moving onto the next row.

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('admin');
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

    /***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/
    function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
        return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
    }

    function _getTableName($tableName){
        return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
    }

    function _getAttributeId($attribute_code = 'price'){
        $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
        $sql = "SELECT attribute_id
                    FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . "
                WHERE
                    entity_type_id = ?
                    AND attribute_code = ?";
        $entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
        return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id, $attribute_code));
    }

    function _getEntityTypeId($entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'){
        $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
        $sql        = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_entity_type') . " WHERE entity_type_code = ?";
        return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_code));
    }

    function _getIdFromSku($sku){
        $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
        $sql        = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
        return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));

    }

    function _checkIfSkuExists($sku){
        $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
        $sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
        $count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
        if($count > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function _updatePrices($data){
        $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
        $sku            = $data[0];
        $newPrice       = $data[1];
        $productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);
        $attributeId    = _getAttributeId();

        $sql = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal') . " cped
                    SET  cped.value = ?
                WHERE  cped.attribute_id = ?
                AND cped.entity_id = ?";
        $connection->query($sql, array($newPrice, $attributeId, $productId));
    }
    /***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/

    $csv                = new Varien_File_Csv();
    $data               = $csv->getData('price-update/PRDAH014.csv'); //path to csv
    array_shift($data);

    $message = '';
    $count   = 1;
    foreach($data as $_data){
        if(_checkIfSkuExists($_data[0])){
            try{
                _updatePrices($_data);
                $message .= $count . '> Success:: While Updating Price (' . $_data[1] . ') of Sku (' . $_data[0] . '). <br />';

            }catch(Exception $e){
                $message .=  $count .'> Error:: While Upating  Price (' . $_data[1] . ') of Sku (' . $_data[0] . ') => '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
            }
        }else{
            $message .=  $count .'> Error:: Product with Sku (' . $_data[0] . ') does\'t exist.<br />';
        }
        $count++;
    }
    echo $message;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the like condition as said from DevZer0 in both functions because they are both called.
The lines of codes at the end will first call `_checkIfSkuExists($_data[0])`, then `_updatePrices($_data)` which calls `$productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);`

Comment: I have tried that but at the moment it is `WHERE sku = ?` so I put `WHERE sku = '%?%'` but not working still.

Comment: You have to change `WHERE sku = ?` into `WHERE sku LIKE ?` and then add a line at the beginning of the function doing a transformation like `$sku = "%" . $sku . "%";`

Comment: I have got that working now, but it stops after only matching one where there may be multiple for example. CSV had `1234` Magenot has `1234_01` and `1234_02` and `1234_03` I need it to update them all with the info from the row in the CSV with `1234` before moving onto the next row. At the moment it moves to the next row after each update instead of searching for more.

Comment: You have to modify a bit more code in this way. You should use fetchAll instead of fetchOne and then modify _updatePrices() looping the productIds returned

Comment: Do you reckon you could help me out a little cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to match the middle portion only, use `%`

```
$sql = "SELECT sku FROM table WHERE item LIKE '%$code%'";
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to put this would it be in both the `_getIdFromSku` and `_checkIfSkuExists` functions?